# WP enqueue javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm making a simple WP Plugin with Index.php and jquery.js files.
How do I link the JS to work together. This is what I tried adding to the index.php, but it did not work. No JS from jquery.js appeared.

```
function my_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . 'jquery.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_scripts');
}
```

Comment: @csixty4 has provided a correct answer but it's important to take a step back... WordPress includes a version of jQuery. You shouldn't be registering your own. Furthermore by giving it the handle script-name rather than jquery you're opening yourself up to the very likely possibility of double loading the jQuery library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is, like Meathanjay pointed out, your add_action needs to be outside the my_scripts() function or else it'll never execute.

`get_template_directory_uri()` is used to get the path to files in a *theme*. For a plugin, you need to use `plugin_dir_url()` and pass it the directory of a file in the plugin's main directory.

`function my_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'jquery.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_scripts');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: your action call within the function and it never call. 
**Update**

```
function my_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/jquery.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_scripts')
```

Comment: Oh, didn't notice. But it still doesn't work. Even a simple alert won't do anything

Comment: You sure your jquery file just in theme folder or in any sub folder?

Comment: Also missing the / before jquery.js

Answer (score 0):

You should Name Unique while adding any script/stylesheet. and you should use `plugins_url()`, or `plugin_dir_url()` in place of `get_template_directory_uri()`.

You can try this if you have more than one scripts and style-sheets to add:

```
function my_scripts() {
    // for Scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('script-unique-name', plugins_url("js/jQuery.js", __FILE__));
    // or
    wp_enqueue_script('script-unique-name2', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)."js/newjQuery.js");

    // for stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style('style-unique-name', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'css/style.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_scripts');

// Or

add_action('admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript'); // Write our JS below here

function my_action_javascript() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Javascript code Here...
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It would be better if you can explain how trying your code out would solve their issue. @DharmeshPatel Cheers! :)

Comment: I mentioned there He should Name Unique while adding any script/stylesheet. and he should use plugins_url(), or plugin_dir_url() and how to use....